# Would asking why the TF2 Market is and began fluctuating be a valid question?

Tags: discussion

I want to know why the TF2 economy started changing crazily, but I don't know if it would be considered a valid question on this site. Should I ask it, or would it likely be closed?

Comment: I am talking about the rise of keys and drop of buds (which leads to the drop of everything else).

Comment: I was about to write an answer but decided against it. I'd be inclined to think that your question pertains more to economics than to gaming. However, if you look up [Diablo 3 questions about the auction house](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiablo-3%5D+auction+house+is%3Aquestion), there are over 100 results. So, I'm not so sure.

Comment: No, because it's a time limited thing. It won't be relevant in a few years' time, or possibly even in the coming months. Most of the Steam Community Market is crashing thanks to the influx of GTAV, in which many players have sold their items for cheap prices to get money for it, causing a lot of normally expensive items to fall down in price quickly.

Comment: @hotlinecalifornia I am not asking about the Steam Community Market, I am asking about the TF2 Market, and what caused it to start going to ruin a couple of years ago.

Comment: @ShadowZ. I would still close it as too localized.  People either claim a few things, either the massive downfall of ref and the rise of price of keys on bp.tf, or others will claim it is the rise of CSGO that lay an end to TF2.

Comment: @hotlinecalifornia So it seems like there would be too many non-concrete answers, and a concrete one would take too long to find?

Comment: @ShadowZ. More like a concrete answer is up to everyone's personal interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

Our experts in TF2 - whilst great at explaining gameplay and strategy & could probably talk about the mechanics of trading - probably don't have a complete  understanding of how the TF2 Economy works and what could cause such a fluctuation.

I feel like any answer would require more than just a *general* understanding of Economics and therefore would require users who can explain what causes market fluctuations in general and why they apply to this specific case.

I think you should consult with [Economics.SE](http://economics.stackexchange.com) instead and see if it is a question they could accept there.

Comment: Although I would also vote questions like these as off topic on our site, you should keep in mind that there are a lot of (online) games with players focusing solely on the economic aspect of the games. I think these questions could be on-topic with a rise of popularity in in-game economics.